# Get a error with post API - Will not send JObject Toke to API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

hat's how I try to get POST some value over to my API. If I remove the "JObject Token", it works fine and then it does not give a fault 500.

But if it's on then it gives up 500.

Code has been taken from MVC over to .net core 2.0

How can I fix the problem so that my values can be submitted to the API?

ERROR HERE:

```
[Route("api/Stripe")]    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post(JObject token)
```

NOT error here:

```
[Route("api/Stripe")]    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post()
```

I have installed Newtonsoft.json in Nuget.

Comment: I feel like this post is missing something, possibly at the top? It's very hard to decipher what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with [FromBody] before your object. 
i mean, something like this

```
[Route("api/Stripe")]    
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] JObject token)
```

i use `[FromBody]` to my apis on .Net, however, in .net core it seems that works the same 
[Json Post on ASP.NET CORE](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/)